# HTML <object>: Issue when formatting PHP call result

Tags: php, html, object-tag

I have a php page which returns a simple integer. I'm calling this page using the html `<object>` tag. I get the result but I cannot format it by changing size, color and the like.

Example of the php:

```
$url = 'https://mydomain/execute.json';

        $request =  $url;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "fih@XXXXXXXXXXXXX);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $json_data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

$data1 = json_decode($json_data, true);

$data1 = $data1['rows'];
echo count($data1);
?>
```

I call this php file like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<span style="font-size:500%"><object width="400" height="400" data="http://anotherdomain/ikketildelte.php"></object></span>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is an integer, but the styling is not effected.

The Chrome developer tools shows that it's embedded in a #document tag:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how to format this result?

Comment: Maybe CURL is making problems here. So, you could try **$json_data = file_get_contents('https:// mydomain/execute.json'); $data1 = json_decode($json_data, true);**

Comment: According to the syntax highlighting in the question, you have a missing `"`